# Google Sheets - How to wrap OR function for Index, Text not working in formula

Tags: google-sheets

At the end of the day, in my Google Sheet I'm trying to filter a large data set by multiple criteria and sum a certain column.  I have a mostly working formula but I'm running into a problem.

Here is an example that works:

```
=sum(INDEX(FILTER('Invoice Data'!H3:P,
'Invoice Data'!N3:N>=DATE(2022,1,1),
('Invoice Data'!H3:H="Arc")+('Invoice Data'!H3:H="Technical Products")
),0,9))
```

The ()+() in the second criteria works well as an OR condition.  However, I want that criteria to be dynamic based on other information.  So I've created the following formula that generates a text string as follows:

```
="('Invoice Data'!H3:H="&CHAR(34)&join(CHAR(34)&")+('Invoice Data'!H3:H="&CHAR(34),FILTER('Dropdown Menus'!D2:D34, A2='Dropdown Menus'!C2:C34))&CHAR(34)&")"
```

This successfully generates the text "('Invoice Data'!H3:H="Arc")+('Invoice Data'!H3:H="Technical Products")".

The problem is, when I put it into the original formula, it doesn't work.

```
=sum(INDEX(FILTER('Invoice Data'!H3:P,
'Invoice Data'!N3:N>=DATE(2022,1,1),
TO_TEXT("('Invoice Data'!H3:H="&CHAR(34)&join(CHAR(34)&")+('Invoice Data'!H3:H="&CHAR(34),FILTER('Dropdown Menus'!D2:D34, A2='Dropdown Menus'!C2:C34))&CHAR(34)&")")
),0,9))
```

I get the following error:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 27436. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

Any thoughts on what might be happening?  I try to use "Indirect()" to have it be a cell reference, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a text string become an executable formula that way.

What you can do is use the [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) function and build the *query statement* dynamically.

For easier debugging, put the formula that builds the query statement text string in a cell of its own, and refer to that cell in the `query()`, like this:

`=query('Invoice Data'!H3:P, S2, 0)`

...where cell `S2` contains your query statement.

Comment: I tried with a query, but in this case I need to reference a new cell each time for the OR categories... not a single select statement to cover all the data.  Is there a way of doing a Query where it just populates into a single cell and not Header with data below?

Comment: Use `select sum(Col9) where... group by... label sum(Col9) ''`. That's two apostrophes rather than a double quote. You can make parts of the query statement optional with `if()`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of your OR try:

```
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER('Invoice Data'!H3:P,
 'Invoice Data'!N3:N>=DATE(2022,1,1), REGEXMATCH(
 'Invoice Data'!H3:H, "(?i)Arc|Technical Products")),,9))
```

where

```
"(?i)Arc|Technical Products"
```

can be dynamically referred as:

```
"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER('Dropdown Menus'!D2:D34, A2='Dropdown Menus'!C2:C34))
```